# SocketServer calls socket.fileno infinitely

Tags: python-2.7, socketserver

Deep diving into python's `SocketServer` module took me to

```
Server.serve_forever()
```

This calls the function `_eintr_retry` with `select.select` as func argument. However, inside `_eintr_retry`, the system call `socket.fileno` is called instead of `select` system call. Why is it so?

And why does the `socket.getfileno()` get invoked infinitely in SocketServer module?

Comment: In `_eintr_retry`, the first parameter `func` - `select.select` in caller's perspective - is called. So `select` is called.

Comment: hi ftru, possibly select calls socket.getfileno(). isn't select.select a C implementation. so, does C function call python's socket.getfileno(). suprised, if the program flow switches between C and python???

Comment: from this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select, i understood `select` call takes objects which has `fileno` method exposed. So, `select` internally needs this to work.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood. [`PyObject_AsFileDescriptor`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_AsFileDescriptor) is used to call `fileno`: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dfe75713f152/Modules/selectmodule.c#l107, https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dfe75713f152/Modules/selectmodule.c#l256

Answer (score 1):

This is not triggered by select.select, but the arguments of select required that the socket list has a method called "fileno", so this is called by the default select argument, but not implementation of "select in C". you can try the following code, which will not call fileno.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    a = server.socket
    select.select([a], [], [], 0.5)
```